# scanf function in for loop is not accepting values

Tags: arrays, c

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 #define SIZE 10

 int main(){

    int i;  

    double array_1[SIZE];                   // array declaration

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)                  // enter array elements
       scanf(" %lf,array_1[i]");
   
    printf("\n%s\n","---------------------");

  //  printf("%s\t%s\n","S.No","Elements");

    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)                  // print array elements
      printf("%3d\t%lf\n",i+1,array_1[i]); 
 }
```

scanf function accepting values for index value 0, subsequently it interrupts abruptly.

Comment: You don't want a leading space in the format string, and you don't want the variab;e you're trying to read in their either.

Comment: You ignore the return value of `scanf()`. Since that is the most appropriate way to determine whether scanning worked or not, but you do not use it: What makes you think that it is not accepting values? And especially (because of the syntax being so far off) that first it did?

Comment: Your compiler should have told you that there is a parameter missing for format specifier `%lf`. You should always read, understand and fix all your warnings and errors before even trying to run your program.

Comment: If you are having trouble understanding an warning message emitted by the compiler, then I suggest that you ask a new question about it. In that place, please quote the exact error message in your question. You should never ignore a warning message, unless you understand it and you are sure that the warning is not justified in your case.

Comment: Devesh Kumar, Save time - enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `&` for reading value

```
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)  
    scanf(" %lf", &array_1[i]);
```

Comment: Not wrong but completely skipping the topic of no parameter for the scan targets being in OPs broken syntax at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)                  // enter array elements
    scanf(" %lf,array_1[i]");
```

Here you told the program that you want to read a value that is followed by ",array_1[i]" you have to close the " after %lf and specify the variable as an argument try

```
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)                  // enter array elements
    scanf(" %lf", &array_1[i]);
```

if this dose not work try without the space yout input will need to have that first space there when you type it

```
scanf("%lf", &array_1[i]);
```